# Django If both product and variant models have color model, how to make Product limit which colors can variant have?

Tags: python, django, model

I have 4 models, product, variant and color.

```
class Size(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class Color(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=400)
    colors = models.ManyToManyField(Color)
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(Size)

class Variant(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10,
                                validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.01'))])
    quantity = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0)])
    color = models.ForeignKey(Color, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In this example a variant can have 1 product, 1 color and 1 size. The problem is the color and size are chosen among all the colors and sizes in the store. I want to limit the color and size in variant to the options of colors and size that were chosen in Product.

If there anyway please let me know. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logically to restrict the conditions as per your requirements, you should override the save method of the Variant model and tell the method to verify the colors and sizes are the ones that belong to current product mentioned in the object to be created.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.color not in self.product.colors.all():
        raise ValidationError("Selected color is not valid <OR ANY MESSAGE YOU WANT TO SHOW>")
    if self.size not in self.product.sizes.all():
        raise ValidationError("Selected color is not valid <OR ANY MESSAGE YOU WANT TO SHOW>")            
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Let me know if it helps or not.

Comment: Thank you Ameer. I think this would work just fine in order to disable the option to choose the not valid choices. but do you think there is anyway to show only the available options ? ( Like limit_options_to) ?

Comment: You will have to do that programmatically. For example where you show your form, the view behind that form must supply the fields for the size and color. 

If you want the form to be dynamic where the user can change product and see relevant size and colors, then simply add an onChange handler on the main select element of product. onChange must send the product to a different Django view through AJAX and send you back the possible size and color options. 

If your form opens with the product already loaded, then its even easier to simply send the relevant size and color options.